# Proving a set is open by defining a continuous function

Tags: general-topology

$A = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: x^2+y^2>4, y<6\}$

Prove the set is open using a continuous function:

My attempt: define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as $f(x,y) =(x^2+y^2,y)$

Now $f$ is continuous and $A  = f^{-1}((4,+\infty)\times(-\infty,6) )$ and that set is open therefore $A$ is open.

Would this be all right? Or should I somehow find a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: It is okay. We have $\pi_i\circ f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ continuous for $i=1,2$ where the $\pi_i$ are projections. Then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @drhab So that's basically the proper solution?

Comment: Yes. In my view it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK like you did it, but (to give you more ideas) you can also use finite intersections: If $\pi_2(x,y) = y$ is the second projection and $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ then both are continuous. (This might need a small extra argument, depending on what you have covered in class). And then $$A = f^{-1}[(4, +\infty)] \cap \pi_2^{-1}[(-\infty, 6)]$$ is open as the finite intersection of two inverse images of open sets under continuous maps.

Using a map into $\mathbb{R}^2$ is correct as well, but such functions might need an extra argument to prove continuity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped with a few other similar, but more difficult problems!!